# how can i find the length of perticular object within the image

Tags: c#

let's say we have an image that contain square,circle and other few object at some distance and now i want to find the length between these object using c#.

Comment: How are you picking out the objects out of the image? Show some code, as otherwise this is much too abstract to answer.

Comment: Yes, it is also really related to computer vision if you are talking about object detection

Comment: it's same like photoshop scale. i want to draw a scale on image that will show me the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you would need to recognize the shapes, for that I would recomend this framework. [aforge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/).

Then for finding the distance read this blog [Computer vision processing in .Net, part II](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/rtaylor/Blog/archive/2008/04/30/computer-vision-processing-in-net-part-ii.aspx)